# Contar registros por mes SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Hola quiero contar los movimientos de una tabla por mes.

 Lo logre pero creando una función y una tabla auxiliar que le puse los 12 meses y en el siguiente campo le agregue la función 
quedando asi:
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura real de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura real de la tabla
La idea es hacerlo con una consulta SQL 
que me de los 12 meses y la cantidad de los movimientos.
No quiero la solución quiero que me expliquen.

Mi consulta es :

```
SELECT COUNT(idMovim) 
                 FROM Movimiento 
                 WHERE YEAR(FchMovim) = YEAR( GETDATE()) AND MONTH(FchMovim) = MES and TipoMovim = 'E'
```

( solo para los movimiento de entrada)
 la cual funciona en la function pero no quiero crear una function y una tabla aux para poder solventarlo en una consulta SQL.

Estructura de la tabla Movmimientos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No termino de entender tu duda y donde requieres apoyo

Comment: Yo tampoco te entiendo... porque dices que lo resolviste y después que no quieres hacerlo así, sino que hacer todo con una sola consulta. Entonces no sirve de nada el Query que pones... vaya, muy liado para explicarlo.

Comment: No quiero crear una tabla para hacer una consulta, si no utilizar una VIEW (vista) como seria esa consulta en una vista?

Comment: @JeffFernando es decir de la consulta que ya tienes y te funciona quieres almacenarla en una vista y poder consultarla de ese modo? entiendo lo que piedes?

Comment: @Aprendiz Si es lo que quería, ya lo solucione

Answer (score 3):

Puedes construir *al vuelo* una *tabla derivada* que te devuelva años y meses. Vamos de lo más simple a lo complejo.

## Años estáticos

Lo más simple que se me ocurre es construir un *CTE* de meses y uno de años, para luego combinarlos. Ejemplo:

```
with 
anio as (
select *
  from (values (2013), (2014), (2015), (2016), (2017), (2018), (2019)
       ) q1 (anio)
)
,
mes as (
select *
  from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
       ) q1 (mes)
)
select anio, mes  
  from anio
       cross join mes;
```

Sobre este *CTE* puedes construir cualquier consulta que requiera años y meses sin requerir del uso de una tabla.

**Pros:**

- La consulta es fácil de escribir y comprender

**Contras:**

- No se va auto-adaptando con el tiempo.

## Desde un año estático hasta el año actual

Para hacerlo un poco más dinámico, necesitamos un generador de números consecutivos, para luego ir sumando a un año estático y parar en el año actual. Una forma *económica* de generar números consecutivos, es *contar registros* en una tabla del sistema que tenga suficientes datos como podamos necesitar. Es común el uso de `sys.all_columns` que suele tener miles de filas. Para años, se puede utilizar otra tabla, pues difícilmente vas a necesitar miles de años. Por lo mismo voy a utilizar `sys.tables`.

```
with 
consecutivo as (
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) n
   from sys.tables
)
,
anio as (
select 1999 + n anio
  from consecutivo
 where 1999 + n <= year(getdate())
)
,
mes as (
select *
  from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
       ) q1 (mes)
)
select anio, mes  
  from anio
       cross join mes;
```

**Pros:**

- La consulta se va auto-adaptando al paso del tiempo

**Contras:**

- El año de inicio es estático
- Muestra todos los meses de todos los años

## Entre el año y mes del primer registro y el año y mes actual

Esta es más funcional, ya que se adapta completamente a los datos y auto-evloluciona con el tiempo, haciendo el *recorte* de los meses previos al primer movimiento en el año inicial y los meses que aún no transcurren del año presente.

Suponiendo que tenemos una tabla de *movimiento*, esto quedaría algo así:

```
with 
fechaMinima as (
select year(fecha) anio, month(fecha) mes
  from (select min(fecha) fecha from Movimiento) q
)
,
consecutivo as (
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) n
   from sys.all_columns
)
,
mes as (
select *
  from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
       ) q1 (mes)
)
select consecutivo.n anio, mes.mes
  from consecutivo
       cross join mes
       cross join fechaMinima
 where consecutivo.n * 100 + mes.mes between fechaMinima.anio * 100 + fechaMinima.mes and year(getdate()) * 100 + month(getdate())
 order by anio, mes;
```

Si observas, en esta ocasión si he cambiado la tabla de base del consecutivo a `sys.all_columns` para asegurarme de no quedarnos cortos en años

**Pros:**

- Se adapta completamente a los datos y al tiempo.

**Contras:**

- La consulta no es tan fácil de comprender para un novato

## Armando el rompecabezas

Hasta ahora hemos visto solamente la parte de obtener una *tabla derivada* de años y meses. Sobre esto, ya se puede construir la consulta real de los datos, por ejemplo, dejando en un *CTE* llamado `aniomes` la consulta de años y meses anterior y haciendo `join` con los movimientos.

```
with 
fechaMinima as (
select year(fecha) anio, month(fecha) mes
  from (select min(fecha) fecha from Movimiento) q
)
,
consecutivo as (
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) n
   from sys.all_columns
)
,
mes as (
select *
  from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
       ) q1 (mes)
)
,
aniomes as (
select consecutivo.n anio, mes.mes
  from consecutivo
       cross join mes
       cross join fechaMinima
 where consecutivo.n * 100 + mes.mes between fechaMinima.anio * 100 + fechaMinima.mes and year(getdate()) * 100 + month(getdate())
)
select aniomes.anio, aniomes.mes, count(movimiento.id) Contador
  from aniomes
       left join movimiento on year(movimiento.fecha) = aniomes.anio and month(movimiento.fecha) = aniomes.mes
 group by aniomes.anio, aniomes.mes
 order by anio, mes;
```

## Consideraciones finales:

Debes tener en cuenta que puede ser una mejor solución tener una tabla de períodos, pues las consultas se simplifican. También puedes hacer una vista hasta la parte de `aniomes`, para que la consulta final sea más fácil de entender.

También, si el volumen de datos es mediano o grande, es mejor tener la fecha inicial y final de cada mes para comparar por rangos y no utilizar las funciones `year()` y `month()`, va a hacer una diferencia en el desempeño de la consulta.